# Can you create a .java file in a c++ program?

Tags: java, c++

Is it possible for me to create a .java file using c++? If so, how?

Comment: Completely possible with file I/O.

Comment: Just like any other text file?

Comment: There are so many ways! Copying a canned .java file could be one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void create_java_file(std::string classname) {
  std::ofstream out(classname + ".java");

  out << "class " << classname << "{ static void main(String [] args) { System.out.println("Hello"); } }";
}

create_java_file("Uhh");
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the quotes.

Answer (score 5):

See [this documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) on Input/Output. If you name your file with a .java at the end then it's a java file.

Comment: I think that's what the OP's looking for.